# Why my object instance's variable were not be able to be accessed correctly in cypress/ it block?

Tags: cypress

In my class object, I have a variable named category, which would be initialed in constructor.

```
export class Page {

  constructor(category) {
    this.category = category;
  }

  categorySession = `[data-cy="${this.category}-form"]`


  enterValue(Value){
    cy.get(this.categorySession).find('Value').type(`${Value}`).should('have.value',`${Value}`)
  }
}
```

When I run the test,
In cypress, it throws me a error [data-cy="undefined-form"], but never found it.

```
import {Page} from "./pages/valuePage"

const LiquidityPage = new Page('Liquidity')

console.log(LiquidityPage.category) <--- it show Liquidity

describe('E2E_case', () => {

  describe('Portfolio Value', () => {
    it('Input Portfolio Value', () => {
      cy.visit('http://localhost:30087/')

      LiquidityPage.enterValue(123)  // this gives me this error -  Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: [data-cy="undefined-form"], but never found it.
     
        })

  })
```

Why is that [data-cy="undefined-form"] but not as my expected value [data-cy="Liquidity-form"]

Answer (score 3):

You would also need to set sessionCategory in the constructor.

That way you will avoid the `undefined` value in the selector string.

```js
export class Page {
  constructor(category) {
    this.category = category;
    this.categorySession = `[data-cy="${this.category}-form"]`
  }
  ...
}
```

But that seems quite obvious, you must have tried it already?

Comment: Oh no, I only tried this console.log(LiquidityPage.category)  instead. , but why it gives me the error? like `categorySession = `[data-cy="${this.category}-form"]` `gives me a undefined error, isnt it a correct initiation?